# Social Network Performance - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i made a social network, testing it in WAMP shows almost 1500 SQL for a single person for a session of about 30 mins and 50 page views !

*[ i'm not using ZEND or APC or MEMCACHED The heaviest page gets loaded within 0.25 second config 512 MB RAM, AMD 1.81GHz ]*

## **Q-> is it ok or i need to less the number of SQL ?**

there are 2 tables PARENT and CHILD
Structure of PARENT table
PID [primary key]
...
...

Structure of CHILD table
ID [primary key]
PID
...
...

*i've not used Foreign Key, but deleting on PARENT also deletes from CHILD
and i made this in PHP/SQL*

## **Q-> is it ok or i should go for FOREIGN KEY for better performance ?**

In PHP i can config how much memory PHP gonna eat
**Q-> can i also do it with MySQL ?**
*[ i am using WAMP,and need to monitor the social network's performance in bottle neck condition ! ]*

Comment: Parsing your questions:  1) Do I need to reduce the number of queries [to avoid db hits and increase application performance]; 2) Would using foreign keys to handle deletes across multiple tables improve performance; 3) How do I configure the db's memory allowance.  I think this post really should be broken into three separate posts.  "Database handling for social networking site best practices" is just too broad.

Comment: as i'm a new member i have to wait for 20 mins for each new post, so i took the shortcut :)

Comment: @Sourav can I know URL of your network?

Comment: @Sourav: Huh? No OpenID Login? :p Just joking. I'll take a look. But it looks nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No-one can say if an arbitrary number of SQL queries is *OK* :

- It depends on the complexity of those queries
- It depends on your database's structure *(indexes, for instance, play a big role)*
- It depends on the amount of data you have
- It depends on how many concurrent users you plan to have *(with one user at a time, your application will probably be way faster than with 100 users at a given instant)*
- ...

Basically : do some benchmarks, using tools such as [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) / [siege](http://www.joedog.org/) / [Jmeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) ; and see if your server can handle the load you expect on having in the next few weeks.

Using foreign keys generally doesn't help with performances *(except if they force you setting indexes you'd need but wouldn't have created by yourself)* : they add some extra-work on the DB side.

But using foreign keys helps with data integrity -- and having data that's OK is probably more important than a couple milliseconds, especially if you are just launching your application *(which means there could be quite a few bugs)*.

Comment: can i set memory to use for MySQL in mysql.ini or my.cnf [or anything like that ?] ?

Answer (score 0):

30 SQL queries per page is reasonable in general (actually it's quite low considering what some CMS do). On the other hand, with the information given, it is not possible to determine whether it is reasonable *in your case*.

Foreign keys do not improve performance. Foreign key constraints might. But they also put business logic into the persistence layer. It's an optimization.

Information about configureing the memory usage of MySQL can be found in the handbook section [7.11.4.1. How MySQL Uses Memory](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-use.html).

Comment: thnx to @Oswald and @Pascal MARTIN

Comment: 30 seems a bit high considering some hosts meter the number of connects and queries.  And, especially high if the database is not on localhost.  Do you have a cite?

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer No, but I remember a talk by Robert Douglass about how various caching strategies in Drupal can reduce the number of queries per page from >300 down to less than 10. http://groups.drupal.org/node/12431 also seems to suggest something in the hundreds.

Comment: "it is not possible to determine whether it is reasonable in your case" is accurate. OP's case would really all depend on too many variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree with Pascal and Oswald - esp. on testing with JMeter or similar to see if you really do have a problem.

I would also load up the database with a few million test profiles to see whether your queries slow down over time. This should help with optimizing query performance.

If your goal for tweaking MySQL is to introduce an artificial bottleneck to test the application, I'd be careful to extrapolate from those tests. What you see with bottlenecks is that they tend to be non-linear - everything is fine until you hit a bottleneck moment, and then everything becomes highly unpredictable. You may not recreate this simply by reducing the memory of the database server.

If there's any low-hanging fruit, I would reduce the number of SQL queries, but 30 queries per page is not excessive. If you want to be prepared to scale to Facebook levels, I don't think reducing the queries per page from 30 to 28 will help much - you need to be ready to partition the application across multiple databases, introduce caching, and buy more powerful hardware.